# Split multiple numbers from a string into an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm looking for a quick PowerShell one-liner to split a string like this:

```
"123.456,789 101-202_303%404..505(606)      707 a bunch of text 808 %%%*&#!@#$%^&*() 909"
```

into an array like this:

```
(123,456,789,101,202,303,404,505,606,707,808,909)
```

Basically, anytime two numbers are separated by anyting *except* a number, then consider those to be two separate numbers.

I have searched online for a solution but haven't quite found what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try `$str -split '\D'`.  `\D` is regex for "anything that is not a digit". If you suspect more than one non-digit in between, use `\D+`

Comment: That was very close, it added extra results for each space, but that can be resolved by doing this `-split '\D' | Where-Object{$_ -ne ""} |  sort -Unique`. Feel free to make that an answer.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on a phone right now, so I won't be doing much typing..

```
$str -split '\D+' | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Should do it.

---

In addition to this, after the `-split`, the elements (although numbers) are still strings. Doing the above sort will therefore sort alphanumeric, not numeric. Since in the example all numbers have three digits, the sort will look fine, but if there are numbers in there with less or more digits, you'll see what I mean:

Lets say your string looks like this:

```
$str = "123.456,789;12 101-202_303%404..505(606)  7    707 a bunch of text 808 %%%*&#!@#$%^&*() 909"
```

Splitting and sorting will give you an array like:

```
101
12
123
202
303
404
456
505
606
7
707
789
808
909
```

If you change the `Sort-Object` just a little to become this:

```
$str -split '\D+' | Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_} -Unique
```

The output will be sorted Numeric so the result is this:

```
7
12
101
123
202
303
404
456
505
606
707
789
808
909
```

Of course, joining the elements after this to become a comma delimited string is as easy as

```
($str -split '\D+' | Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_} -Unique) -join ','
```

Output:

```
7,12,101,123,202,303,404,456,505,606,707,789,808,909
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get replace all none digits and then clear empty array parts

```
"123.456,789 101-202_303%404..505(606)      707 a bunch of text 808 %%%*&#!@#$%^&*() 909" -split '\D' | ?({ $_ -ne "" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "123.456,789 101-202_303%404..505(606)      707 a bunch of text 808 %%%*&#!@#$%^&*() 909"
$y = $x -split '[^\d]+(?=\d+)'
```

Result:

```
$y -join ','  #   123,456,789,101,202,303,404,505,606,707,808,909
```